# PrimeNg - make dynamically created dialog draggable

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dialog

I am using PrimeNg library. It has nice `<p-dialog>` component, which creates dialogs draggable by default. But in certain context, I am using PrimeNg's API `dialogService`, to create the dialog dynamically. Notice the `this.dialogService.open()`.

But in this case, the dialog is not draggable.

Is there any workaround to make it work?

**Sample code**

```
class MyClass {
constructor(private readonly dialogService: DialogService) {}

    openDialog(options: KonsolidacniKonfliktDialogOptions): DynamicDialogRef {
        const dialogRef = this.dialogService.open(SomeComponentToRenderInsideDialog, {
            header: options.dialogHeader,
            width: this.dialogWidth,
            height: this.dialogHeight,
            styleClass: this.dialogStyleClass,
            data: {
                whatever: options.whatever,
            },
        });

        return dialogRef;
    }
}
```

Comment: Link to GitHub feature request: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/7811

Answer (score 0):

In this example the dialog box is draggable :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-dialog-yodw4v

Comment: Yes, but they are using the `<p-dialog>` component, not the `dynamicDialog` invoked via API. The `<p-dialog>` can only display already known content, not dynamic one. Or I would have to bend it and hack it, which seems like an overkill

Comment: we can make  prime Ng Dynamic Dialog draggable with the help of directive

Answer (score 0):

Here's a directive to achieve the required drag behavior

```ts
import {AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, Input, NgZone, OnDestroy} from "@angular/core";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { map, switchMap, takeUntil } from "rxjs/operators";



@Directive({
  selector: "[draggabel]"
})
export class DraggabelDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy  {


  @Input() dragHandle: string;
  @Input() dragTarget: string;

  // Element to be dragged
  private target: HTMLElement;
  // Drag handle
  private handle: HTMLElement;
  private delta = {x: 0, y: 0};
  private offset = {x: 0, y: 0};



  private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private zone: NgZone) {
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.handle = this.dragHandle ? document.querySelector(this.dragHandle) as HTMLElement :
      this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    this.target = document.querySelector(this.dragTarget) as HTMLElement;
    this.setupEvents();
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
  }

  private setupEvents() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      const mousedown$ = fromEvent(this.handle, "mousedown");
      const mousemove$ = fromEvent(document, "mousemove");
      const mouseup$ = fromEvent(document, "mouseup");

      const mousedrag$ = mousedown$.pipe(
        switchMap((event: MouseEvent) => {
          const startX = event.clientX;
          const startY = event.clientY;

          return mousemove$.pipe(
            map((event: MouseEvent) => {
              event.preventDefault();
              this.delta = {
                x: event.clientX - startX,
                y: event.clientY - startY
              };
            }),
            takeUntil(mouseup$)
          );
        }),
        takeUntil(this.destroy$)
      );

      mousedrag$.subscribe(() => {
        if (this.delta.x === 0 && this.delta.y === 0) {
          return;
        }

        this.translate();
      });

      mouseup$.pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroy$)
      ).subscribe(() => {
        this.offset.x += this.delta.x;
        this.offset.y += this.delta.y;
        this.delta = {x: 0, y: 0};
      });
    });
  }

  private translate() {
    const xNewPosition = this.offset.x + this.delta.x;
    const yNewPosition = this.offset.y + this.delta.y;
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      this.target.style.transform = `
        translate(${xNewPosition}px,
                  ${yNewPosition}px)
      `;
    });
  }
}
```

Usage:

```html
<some-dialog draggabel
             dragTarget=".p-dynamic-dialog" 
             dragHandle=".p-dynamic-dialog"
>
</some-dialog>
```

it's based on Oleg Varaksin Medium [Blog](https://olegvaraksin.medium.com/draggable-directive-and-how-to-make-angular-material-dialog-draggable-b112fa588bca) with RxJs code and observable imports updated to use `pipe()`